# Code matching algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two java source code files that do the same thing, give the same output. They differ a little in code they contain like in the example below. I need an algorithm that derteminates the rate of likeness (sameness) between these two java code files.

Example

```
/* First file */
public int inc (int n) {
    return ++n;
}

/* Second file */
public int inc (int n) {
    return (n+1);
}
```

Is there an algorithm that shows that these two files do the same thing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can check the output always to see if its the same or not. There can be many ways same thing can be achieved. It depends on how to actually implement it. You should make sure that you want the similarity in *Way* or the *Destination/Result*

Comment: In the general case, determining whether two programs do the same thing (for all inputs) is an undecidable problem (I believe).  You may be able to do better in specific cases, though.  For example, if you can show that your code has no side-effects (i.e. is pure), then you could brute-force over all input values and compare.

Comment: Depends on what your programs do. If they generate some text output (or even number as a result) you can always compare results. Otherwise - just compare the code with BeyondCompare for example.

Comment: Yes but how do i understand that i have not just printed the result.

Comment: @ErionLika: print it

Comment: Is there any algorithm that does code compare for likeness ??

Comment: I wonder if you could check the compiled versions of the example code and compare that. The compiler most likely treats `n+1` and `n++` as the same object. At least for this example that could be a possibility.

Comment: @ErionLika There is no simple algorithm. It is conceivable that with modern machine learning techniques you could determine a "level of similarity" between two sets of code. You need to clarify your question as there are two distinct questions in it. 1) Is there an algorithm that shows that these two files do the same thing ? and 2) an algorithm that derteminates the rate of likeness (sameness). These are different things.

Answer (score 4):

As proved by Alan Turing almost a century ago, no general algorithm exists which could even determine whether a function's evaluation will complete in finite time (see *the Halting problem*).

By implication there is no general algorithm which could decide whether two pieces of code have the same output. On the other hand, if you assume that the functions always complete in finite time, then a trivial algorithm that does what you want is one which simply runs the code in question for all possible inputs.

Comment: That's assuming the set of "all possible inputs" is finite.  Consider strings/input-streams/network-connections as a counterexample.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth We don't even need to go that far---it stops being feasible just around a length of 20 bytes or so :)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring all the intricate details, Here is a naive school level algorithm to do this.

**Test 1**:First count the number of variables used in both programs.See the difference between them and decide a threshold difference for passing the test depending upon your needs and the programs you are comparing.

**Test 2**:Then determine the data type of variable that is used maximum times in both programs and if the data type differs then in most cases the programs will differ but again, It is not always the case.

**Test 3**:You could compare their **cyclomatic complexity**. This could also help in determining the likeness as it tell you about the number of **independent paths** in your programs.

**There can be many more tests like comparing the number of blocks or function calls and you could set the rate of likeness to be equal to percentage of tests passed**.

**But of course This algorithm is naive and will have test cases for which it will fail, but for the basics and a start I think it should do fine.**

Answer (score 0):

No such algorithm exists unfortunately.

Why? See: https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/computability/undecidable.html

specifically the section labeled "The Equivalence Problem is Undecidable"

To truly understand why it would help to familiarize yourself in such areas as decidability, turing machines, and various other types of automata

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking forward to write a program which detects similar work, you can try searching how software `Turnitin` works.

While it is not possible to come out with an algorithm which works for all cases. There is some work around solutions you can adopt.

1. You can create "synonyms" for certain words/code. Example `x++` similar to `x+=1`, `x=x+1`, `++x` and so on. However note that sometimes `x++` and `++x` mean totally different things in coding. So your program can never be 100% accurate to judge the similarity.
2. Your database of "synonyms" must be large enough to handle various cases.

However, take note that people can always bypass your detection by *obfuscating* their codes or adding confusion to it.

**Example**: instead of writing `x++`, they could write `x=(x+2)-1` which means the same thing and no matter how large your database of synonyms are, you can never catch that.

3. If you program does not only check on codes, but on essays and journals as well. You can make a text analysis on writing patters. (For example using word length frequency count). Some authors may prefer to use shorter words, while some prefer longer words.
4. There are many other analysis you can come out with to make your program a dynamic one. Even though there is no such algorithm, but it is definitely possible to write such programs to detect plagiarism.